# Dynamic use of fragment in Thymeleaf - Spring Boot / reload a part of a page dynamically onChange/onClick whatever

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

as the title indicates, I am trying to create a page, more precisely a form which part of it must be reloaded when an element of the page is changed (onChange)

I use Thymeleaf for the frontend and Spring Boot for the backend.

Theoretically in Thymeleaf, we are supposed to send directly via the controller the fragment and receive it as a complete fragment.

By putting `model.addAttribute()` inside the Get request for the fragment, + having well made the page of our fragment on the Thymeleaf side, it's supposed to do things automatically, that is to say give me the fragment already built in hand when I'm going to make a call via the fetch or via an ajax in order to receive the response (the fragment).

So I'll just need to take the part of the page I want to replace via a getElementById and do a load(response)

The problem is that I get a string and not the constructed fragment

That is, I get `fragments/underHeadingList :: input`, as a String. I guess it doesn't work.

However, when I put,

`<div th:replace="fragments/underHeadingList :: input"></div>"`

directly in my code, it works and calls the fragment

The problem of course is that the list that this fragment is supposed to display, changes depending on the element selected during the on change

Here is my code:

[controller]

```
import be.mutualit.dto.UnderHeadingDTO;
import be.mutualit.service.UnderHeadingService;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("underHeading")
public class UnderHeadingController {

    private final UnderHeadingService underHeadingService;

    public UnderHeadingController(UnderHeadingService underHeadingService) {
        this.underHeadingService = underHeadingService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("getAllLinkToHeadingID")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAllLinkToHeadingID(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        Locale locale = (Locale) session.getAttribute("locale");
        List<UnderHeadingDTO> allLinkToHeadingIDByLanguage = underHeadingService.getAllLinkToHeadingIDByLanguage(713, locale);
        model.addAttribute("underHeadingList", allLinkToHeadingIDByLanguage);
        return "fragments/underHeadingList :: input";
    }

}
```

[fragment html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<!--/*@thymesVar id="underHeadingList" type="java.util.List<be.mutualit.dto.UnderHeadingDTO>"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="underHeading" type="be.mutualit.dto.UnderHeadingDTO"*/-->
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<div th:fragment="input">
    <label for="underHeadingSelect" th:text="#{addActionProblem.underHeading}"></label>
    <select id="underHeadingSelect" name="underHeadingSelect" th:field="*{underHeadingID}" style="font-size: 12px;">
        <option th:each="underHeading : ${underHeadingList}"
                th:value="${underHeading.id}"
                th:text="${underHeading.label}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('underHeadingID')}" th:errors="*{underHeadingID}"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

[JS part]

```
function onChangeSelectHeading() {
$.get('/underHeading/getAllLinkToHeadingID', function (fragment) {
    console.log(fragment)
    $("#underHeadingDiv").replaceWith(fragment);
});
```

}

[Page]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorate="~{layouts/layout}">
<!--/*@thymesVar id="headingList" type="java.util.List<be.mutualit.dto.HeadingDTO>"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="heading" type="be.mutualit.dto.HeadingDTO"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="actionList" type="java.util.List<be.mutualit.dto.HeadingDTO>"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="action" type="be.mutualit.dto.HeadingDTO"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="contactList" type="java.util.List<be.mutualit.dto.HeadingDTO>"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="contact" type="be.mutualit.dto.HeadingDTO"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="underHeadingList" type="java.util.List<be.mutualit.dto.UnderHeadingDTO>"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="actionProblem" type="be.mutualit.dto.ActionProblemForm"*/-->
<body>
<div id="container_main" class="container">
    <div id="content" layout:fragment="content">
        <div class="code">
            <form id="formAddActionProblem" action="#" th:action="@{/addActionProblem}" method="post" th:object="${actionProblem}">
                <div class="block mb-3 mt-2">
                    <label for="id">Id</label>
                    <input id="id" disabled type="text" th:field="*{id}"/>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('id')}" th:errors="*{id}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="block mb-4">
                    <label for="creationDate" th:text="#{addActionProblem.date}"></label>
                    <input id="creationDate" type="datetime-local" th:field="*{creationDate}"/>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('creationDate')}" th:errors="*{creationDate}"></div>
                </div>
                <p class="mb-1" style="font-size: 13px" th:text="#{addActionProblem.underTitle.duration}"></p>
                <div class="block mb-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-1"><label for="hourDuration" th:text="#{addActionProblem.hour}"></label>
                            <input style="width: 60px;" id="hourDuration" type="number" min="0" th:field="*{hourDuration}"/>
                            <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('hourDuration')}" th:errors="*{hourDuration}"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1"><label for="minuteDuration" th:text="#{addActionProblem.minute}"></label>
                            <input style="width: 60px;" id="minuteDuration" type="number" min="0" max="60" th:field="*{minuteDuration}"/>
                            <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('minuteDuration')}" th:errors="*{minuteDuration}"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="mb-1" style="font-size: 13px" th:text="#{addActionProblem.underTitle.fileType}"></p>
                <div class="block mb-3">
                    <label for="headingSelect" th:text="#{addActionProblem.heading}"></label>
                    <select id="headingSelect" name="headingSelect" th:field="*{headingID}" th:onchange="onChangeSelectHeading()" style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <option th:each="heading : ${headingList}"
                                th:value="${heading.id}"
                                th:text="${heading.label}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('headingID')}" th:errors="*{headingID}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="block mb-3">
                    <div id="underHeadingDiv">
                        <div th:replace="fragments/underHeadingList :: input"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block mb-3">
                    <label for="actionSelect" th:text="#{addActionProblem.action}"></label>
                    <select id="actionSelect" name="actionSelect" th:field="*{actionID}" style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <option th:each="action : ${actionList}"
                                th:value="${action.id}"
                                th:text="${action.label}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('actionID')}" th:errors="*{actionID}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="block mb-3">
                    <label for="contactSelect" th:text="#{addActionProblem.contactMode}"></label>
                    <select id="contactSelect" name="contactSelect" th:field="*{contactTypeID}" style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <option th:each="contact : ${contactList}"
                                th:value="${contact.id}"
                                th:text="${contact.label}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('contactTypeID')}" th:errors="*{contactTypeID}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <p class="mb-1" th:text="#{addActionProblem.incomingOutgoing}"></p>
                    <input id="incoming" name="incomingOutgoing" type="radio" th:text="' ' + #{addActionProblem.incoming} + ' '"
                           th:field="*{incomingOutgoing}" value="E"/>
                    <label for="incoming"></label>
                    <input id="outgoing" name="incomingOutgoing" type="radio" th:text="' ' + #{addActionProblem.outgoing} + ' '"
                           th:field="*{incomingOutgoing}" value="S"/>
                    <label for="outgoing"></label>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('incomingOutgoing')}" th:errors="*{incomingOutgoing}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="block mb-3">
                    <label for="comment" th:text="#{addActionProblem.comment}"></label>
                    <textarea id="comment" style="width: 446px; height: 126px;" rows="8" cols="6" th:field="*{comment}"></textarea>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('comment')}" th:errors="*{comment}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="float-end">
                    <img class="buttonFormPicture"
                         th:src="@{images/save.png}"
                         alt="save button"/>
                    <button class="buttonForm" type="submit" th:text="#{addActionProblem.save}"></button>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                    <img class="buttonFormPicture"
                         th:src="@{images/cancel.png}"
                         alt="cancel button"/>
                    <button class="buttonForm" type="button" th:onclick="onClickCancelButton()" th:text="#{addActionProblem.cancel}"></button>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${message}" th:text="${message}" th:class="${'alert ' + alertClass}"></div>
                <br/><br/>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ActionProblemForm (DTO)

```
import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ActionProblemForm implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4259040663789461901L;

    private int id;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "{addActionProblem.constraint.hour.min}")
    private int hourDuration;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "{addActionProblem.constraint.minute.min}")
    @Max(value = 60, message = "{addActionProblem.constraint.minute.max}")
    private int minuteDuration;

    private int headingID;

    private int underHeadingID;

    private int actionID;

    private int contactTypeID;

    private char incomingOutgoing;

    private String comment;
}
```

UnderHeadingDTO

```
import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UnderHeadingDTO implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6048713942983512203L;

    private int id;
    private String label;
}
```

Edit :

When I remove "form part" from the fragment code, the code is working and does not show anymore String.

So now the problem is that I need to find a way to when I submit the form, to get also data from the fragment.

```
th:field="*{underHeadingID}"
```

because without this part inside my fragment, I do not receive the data inside my controller

Comment: Thanks James, I just modified it